# List expander in property grid , with genric ICustomTypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, list, propertygrid, icustomtypedescriptor

I have a generic class (`Parameters.cs`) that implements the interface: `ICustomTypeDescriptor`.

I use the generic class for several different classes, one of which is this:

```
    private Parameters<Class1> _class1Parameters;

    public Parameters<Class1> Class1Parameters
    {
        get { return _class1Parameters; }
        set { _class1Parameters= value; }
    }
```

Class1.cs:

```
public class Class1
{
    private List<Position> _pos = new List<Position>();

    public List<Position> Pos
    {
        get { return _pos ; }
        set { _pos = value; }
    }  

    //Other variables
}
```

Position class:

```
public class Position
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Position { get; set; }
}
```

Right now the list is displayed with three points in Propertygrid ("...").

I want it to be displayed with Expander ("+"), how can we do it through the  `ICustomTypeDescriptor`?

**EDIT:**

I tried putting `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]` over the `Pos` list, it did not help.

Comment: What object you are displaying in property grid?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, the list of position

Comment: And how your generic `Parameters` class related to question?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, in generic `Paramerters` I implements the interface: `ICustomTypeDescriptor`. and the property grid use it : `Parameters<Class1>`.

Comment: You said just above it uses list of positions. Which should not be problem - if you will assign list of positions to property grid, it will allow to see all positions in collection editor. Also you didn't specify what you are using - is it WinForms?

Comment: I mean each option is for another property grid, @lazyberezovsky, and yes is it WinForms.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, I do not want the collection editor, I want it will be with expander, this is my question.

Comment: What property exactly is displayed with '...' in the grid? Class1Parameters? Pos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it through this site:

**[Customized display of collection data in a PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert)**